# Which remote desktop renders fast

Tags: pi-3, remote, vnc, android

I tried to use my Android to remotely view and control my pi 3 desktop with tightvncserver on the pi 3.

The problem is its not rendering fast and when I open some applications remotely on my Android, the view will be on Pi 3 HDMI monitor instead on the vnc viewer.

Are there any fast better way to view video stream remotely and also be able to adjust screen resolutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "fastest" and most efficient way to stream HDMI-out (and optionally audio too) remotely to .e.g a web browser is **[UV4L](http://linux-projects.org)**. It does not require any plug-in installed on the browser. This is a [demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wthS8TPk2DE&feature=youtu.be) which clearly show this. You can also control the Rpi from the browser.

Answer (score 1):

RealVNC Server & Viewer now come installed by default on Raspbian - if you follow the instructions on [this blog post](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/introducing-pixel/) by the Raspberry Pi Foundation you can update to the latest version and then enable VNC Server from the Raspberry Pi Configuration program (or `sudo raspi-config` at the terminal).

I have found they work very well with Raspberry Pi 3 and older Pi versions down to B+, and there is a viewer for Android.

Usually the quality adapts to your connection speed, but if it's rendering too slowly you can try adjusting quality for best speed.

FYI there is also an experimental mode for 'directly rendered' programs like Minecraft; if you are having issues with some programs not displaying you can try enabling that - more details [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/vnc/).

Comment: No problem!  Don't forget to mark the question as answered ;)